# Why do I have a 200ms request period in Wireshark when I configure it for 100ms in the Modbus task, using ST language in TwinCAT3?

Tags: wireshark, twincat, st

I create a program to obtain data through Modbus-TCP server (192.168.2.16) on TwinCAT3 to obtain data from other PC (slave: 192.168.2.20):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abtbm.png)

Also I create and configure the modbus server task with 100ms.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO0jY.png)

However, I noted in wireshark that the period of request is around 200ms and not 100ms. Why the period is 200ms?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrfzV.jpg)

I was hoping that the period would be the same (100ms)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For future posts, try providing `the code as text` (can be formatted to display as code section), instead of images of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Your function-block is taking more than a single cycle to run.

---

### Explanation

Depending on the application a function-block can take multiple cycles to complete, which is why they are often configured with:

- bExecute: The function-block is activated on a rising edge at this input
- bBusy: Indicates TRUE while the function-block is running

In your case I believe that you will be seeing a single cycle of bBusy being high after you have set bExecute to TRUE. This is often the case when a function-block needs to communicate with some external object (like a network device).

---

### Solution

The recommended solution to your timing problem is to reduce your cycle time (5/10ms should do), and then set 'bExecute' on your desired cycle time.
This allows the function-block to run for several cycles and return its data before starting a new request.

Comment: Hi @Steve, Im sorry for my late response.

I only have one cycle task (modbus). When I put 50ms on the cycle task I get 100ms request period on wireshark. So the relation between the cycle task and request period is 2:1. However, I dont understand why the request period is not around the cycle task.

Comment: `PROGRAM ModbusCommunication
VAR
 fbMBReadCoils : FB_MBReadCoils;
 nReadValue : BYTE;
END_VAR

IF fbMBReadCoils.bBusy = FALSE AND fbMBReadCoils.bError = FALSE THEN
fbMBReadCoils(sIPAddr:= '192.168.2.20', nTCPPort:= 1504, nUnitID:= 16#FF, nQuantity:= 1, nMBAddr:= 0, cbLength:= SIZEOF(nReadValue), pDestAddr:= ADR(nReadValue), bExecute:= TRUE, tTimeout:= , bBusy=> , bError=> , nErrId=> , cbRead=> );
 

 
ELSE
 fbMBReadCoils(bExecute:= FALSE);
END_IF`

Comment: The important aspect to consider is that the FB is starting an asynchronous process to send a message to the device and then receive its response.  
Therefore it requires at least 2 cycles to perform its function: 1. Send data to the async process, 2. Read data back from the async process.